# Integrating Material UI in Angular 11

Tags: angular, angular-material, integration

I have been working with Angular 8 and Material UI some time back (before release of 10 or 11) , where I had a file that imported all Material UI components, however when I tried to do the same in Angular 11, I am getting errors. If I import individually, it compiles but if I import as a file (that imports all the components) , I am getting error as below -

```
Error: ./src/app/material.module.ts
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/index.js):
Error: D:\Angular app\form\src\app\material.module.ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation. 
Please make sure it is 
in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property.
at AngularCompilerPlugin.getCompiledFile (D:\Angular 
app\form\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\angular_compiler_plugin.js:951:23)
at D:\Angular app\form\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\loader.js:43:31
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:89:5)

                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Included as import {MaterialModule} from './material.module' in app.module.ts .

Comment: So... import them individually, as you should. Only import what you need.

Comment: I did and it works but just to keep clean , I wanted to import as a file.

Comment: I think the issue could be, `import { MatIconModule} from "@angular/material"` should change to `import { MatIconModule} from "@angular/material/icon"` and follow similar way for all other modules

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to fix it , the components need to be called individually in the material.module.ts file unlike previous versions.